# Declare many variables in a single loop (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

Alright guys, my problem is, I want to declare 24 variables. I could use this line:

```
string p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10 ,p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23;
```

But, this doesn't seem like the right way to do it, so I tried to use a loop to do it for me.

```
for (int i = 0;i<=23;++i)
{
    char b = i;
    string p[b];
    p[b] = "-";
    cout << p[b];
}
```

Mind not the final part about definind and printing the variable, this is gonna change. The problem, however, is that this code works (get compiled without errors) but instantly crashes (Program.exe stopped working...). Which would be the right way to do it?

EDIT:

Many people don't seem to understand:

I'm sorry I wasn't clear, p is no array. I want to create the variables p0 then p1 and so forward in a loop, but I don't know how to express the fact that the character just after 'p' is changing ( and so the variable) for each loop.

Comment: "works but instantly crashes" = doesn't work.

Comment: As you may see, SO is not very newbie friendly. Even though it's clear you're a programmer in his first baby steps, I've gone through that a very long time ago too, your kind is the first to get your questioning downvoted.

Comment: Then why not use an array? That's exactly why arrays exist.

Comment: Should've thought more before posting, my fault here.

Comment: At least you will get helpful answers. The downvotes for beginners are typically because beginners don't know enough to ask good questions. That's a natural consequence of being a beginner. And by good questions I mean things that could help future visitors.

Comment: @tenfour this kind of misconception being well removed by a good answer I see helping a lot of newbies. It's not in the scope of practical and well crafted questioning, but I feel this kind of misconception frequent in the newbie population, so it can help future newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to "give names" to each of the elements in the array. You simply **cannot** do that.

Just make an array of size 24 (From 0 to 23) and don't try to "name" each element as you're doing now, your elements will be `p[0]`, `p[1]`.. until `p[23]`.

Comment: Thanks, the only answer I needed then, someone got it.

Comment: @user3258512 I can not think why would you like to 'name' a variable in a specific way. With arrays you will achieve that but instead of your variable name being `p0,p1,p2...` it will be `p[0],p[1],p[2]..`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what you're trying to do in your code. Here's my best guess:

```
string p[24];// this allocates your 24-string array

for (int i = 0;i<24;++i)
{
    p[i] = "-";
    cout << p[i];
}
```

See you must define your array with a fixed size before you start using it. Your code compiles but it doesn't do what you think it does. I have annotated your original code:

```
for (int i = 0;i<=23;++i)
{
    char b = i;// this seems pointless; basically it does nothing. Keep in mind that a char is just a number. i is already a number.
    string p[b];// allocates an array of strings with b elements. This creates a new, empty, array for *each iteration*. This is definitely not what you want.
    p[b] = "-";// sets the b-th element of the array to "-". This should crash. In a 24-element array, the 24th element is out of bounds. You can only access indices 0-23.
    cout << p[b];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time in your loop, the array is "size-zero", and then you access an element past the end of the array.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, p is no array. I want to create the variables p0 then p1 and so forward in a loop, but I don't know how to express the fact that the character just after 'p' is changing ( and so the variable) for each loop.

Comment: @user3258512 `p` is an array, you declared as such.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing an array out of bounds.

```
string p[b];
p[b] = "-";
```

You're declaring an array with `b` number of elements so valid indexes are in the range **0 up to `b`-1**. But then you're trying to index at position `b`.

Also the first time in the loop `b` is zero and arrays with a size of 0 aren't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're trying to do..
It seems that you are trying to print the following lines using C++ programming:

```
"string p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10 ,p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23;"
```

and not actually to use those variables declaration in your own code..
Are you coding to generate another code?

```
for (int i = 0;i<=23;++i)
{
    char b = i;
    string p[b]; // why do you declare like this? 
    p[b] = "-";
    cout << p[b];
}
```